How to create a YAML file to support .NET 6, .NET 7, .NET 8?
My project has multiple frameworks
net6.0;net7.0;net8.0
I created a YAML file and everything works, but when I set it to .NET 8, meaning a single framework.
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: echo 'Starting the build'
  displayName: 'Starting Build'

- script: dotnet restore
  displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore
  displayName: 'Build Project'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -property:TargetFramework=net8.0'
    zipAfterPublish: false
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'myAppBuild'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  displayName: 'Publish Build Artifact'

I need a solution that supports .NET 6, .NET 7, and .NET8

Support multiple .NET Framework versions in your project file

I need YAML file with multiple support

You can try using matrix strategy for your `jobs:

job: BuildAndPublish
displayName: Build and Publish
strategy:
matrix:
net6:
framework: 'net6.0'
net7:
framework: 'net7.0'
net8:
framework: 'net8.0'`


You can use an object type runtime parameter to pass all the three target frameworks to the build job.
parameters:
- name: TargetFrameworks
  type: object
  default:
    - 'net8.0'
    - 'net7.0'
    - 'net6.0'

steps:
- script: echo 'Starting the build'
  displayName: 'Starting Build'

- script: dotnet restore
  displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore
  displayName: 'Build Project'

- ${{ each Framework in parameters.TargetFrameworks }}:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact - ${{ Framework }}'
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ Framework }} -property:TargetFramework=${{ Framework }}'
      zipAfterPublish: false

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'myAppBuild'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  displayName: 'Publish Build Artifact'

With this way, the pipeline will copy 3 dotnet publish tasks for the 3  target frameworks within the same job.

